# Animate Zurb Foundation top-bar dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to slide down the top-bar menus dropdown elements using Zurb foundation.

So far i have:

```
$('.top-bar .has-dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown').first().stop(true, true).slideUp()
});
```

But it doesn't slide the whole thing down, it just shows the menu and then moves it down a bit!

Comment: I was noticing the same thing with my dropdowns and found the culprit was the _top-bar.scss in the line: height: auto !important. Have you found a solution to this? I really would not like to write over the _top-bar.scss file.